# Can I use OAuth 2.0 Service-to-service access token to access Skype for Business Online Resources?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, skype-for-business

My question is about Skype for Business Online. I'm able to connect with ucwa sdk samples and get the current status of the user. In the sample the user is required to authenticate, but I need a solution that runs in the background.
I want to get the presence of an SfB online user without going through the login screen.

I followed this link: [Service-to-service access token request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#request-an-access-token)

Can I use the OAuth 2.0 service-to-service method to get SfB Online resources?

If not, Are there other method(s) to do this?

I'm able to retrieve an acces token from the code below, but unable to connect with SfB as I don't know what do next.

```
def get_access_token(resource):
params = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
  'client_id': clientId,
  'client_secret': secret,
  'resource': resource
}

url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/%s/oauth2/token' % tenant)

response = requests.post(url, params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    jsonObject = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    print(jsonObject)
    return jsonObject['access_token']
else:
    print(response.content)
```